# Can't get a Maven repo working with Nexus Server

Tags: java, maven, repository, nexus, svnkit

I'm a bit new to Maven. I thought I was getting a pretty good handle on it. I guess not.
I want to set up a dependency on SVNKit 1.7.0-alpha1. According to their [website](http://svnkit.com/download.php), They have a releases repo located at http://maven.tmatesoft.com/content/repositories/releases/

Also, they shared:

```
GroupId: org.tmatesoft.svnkit
ArtifactIds: svnkit, ...
version: 1.3.7, 1.3.8-SNAPSHOT, 1.7.0-alpha1, 1.7.0-SNAPSHOT
```

So, I added the following to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0-alpha1</version>
</dependency>
```

And

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>tmatesoft-releases</id>
    <url>http://maven.tmatesoft.com/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
<repository>
    <id>tmatesoft-snapshots</id>
    <url>http://maven.tmatesoft.com/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    <releases>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>tmatesoft-releases</id>
        <url>http://maven.tmatesoft.com/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>tmatesoft-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://maven.tmatesoft.com/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
    <distributionManagement>
    ...
    </distributionManagement>
</repositories>
```

But when I do a maven build on the project, it doesn't appear to even check the repo I provided.

Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong here?

**UPDATE**

Found the answer. One of our company's more experienced buildmasters gave me a bit of background on how a nexus server works. I had a sneaking suspicion that the dependencyManagement section was relevant.

To fix this (if you have a Nexus server), you'll have to add the third-party repo to the Nexus Server. Then it should work fine.

Comment: Can you post the maven output, where it attempts to fetch the dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. One of our company's more experienced buildmasters gave me a bit of background on how a nexus server works. I had a sneaking suspicion that the dependencyManagement section was relevant.

To fix this (if you have a Nexus server), you'll have to add the third-party repo to the Nexus Server. Then it should work fine.